# Notice: Undefined index: sid in C:\wamp\www\test\inc\template.php on line 205

Tags: php

im still new to php , and i got this error .. pls help me out here , thx .

Notice: Undefined index: sid in C:\wamp\www\test\inc\template.php on line 205

so , here is my code :

```
<?php
}
elseif($_SESSION['sid'] != '')
{
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['sid']` see the index, 'sid' ? Well, is undefined, so either you don't have a 'sid' index set, or you don't have the whole $_SESSION set. Did you use `session_start()` ?

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` is an array so you set it like so `$_SESSION['sid'] = 'some sid';` if you try to use `$_SESSION['sid']` without setting it then PHP throws a notice.

If you want to avoid the notice then one of these options will work:

**Option 1**

```
<?php
// check if the variable isset before using it
if(isset($_SESSION['sid']) && $_SESSION['sid'] != '')
{
    // do something
}
?>
```

**Option 2**

```
<?php
// turn off error reporting
// NEVER DO THIS IN A DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT
// error_reporting(E_ALL) should be used in development
error_reporting(0);

if($_SESSION['sid'] != '')
{
    // do something
}
?>
```

Comment: NEVER turn off error reporting when still in development!! :D Option one gave you my +1

Comment: @JoranDenHouting right you are, comments in option #2 have been updated =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if a session variable is set (or any variable for that matter), use `isset()`. If you just want to see if it is empty, use `empty()` *after* using `isset()`

```
elseif(isset($_SESSION['sid']) && !empty($_SESSION['sid']))
```